# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)s for +: 'StringVar' and 'str' // Create a text file

Tags: python, file, text, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a script that creates a text file, and the name of that text file corresponds to what was entered by the user. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*

fenetre = Tk()
def creation():
    open(f1 + '.txt', "w")
Label1 = Label(fenetre, text = 'Nom de votre classe :')
Label1.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
f1 = StringVar()
Champ = Entry(fenetre, textvariable= f1, bg ='bisque', fg='maroon')
Champ.focus_set()
Champ.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
Bouton = Button(fenetre, text ='Valider', command = creation())
Bouton.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5, pady = 5)
fenetre.mainloop()
```

But it doesn't work and gives the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)s for +: 'StringVar' and 'str'
```

I succeeded to create the file once, but it didn't got a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `f1.get()` when you want to use the value. `f1` itself is not a string, but rather an object that can hold a string. Calling the `get()` method on it returns the actual string it is holding.

```
def creation():
    open(f1.get() + '.txt', "w")
```

Comment: Thanks a lots that works and i solved another problem, my script created a file when I launched it, I erased the () after Bouton = Button(fenetre, text ='Valider', command = creation())